# Vagrant. Copy file from guest (darwin, OSX) to host (darwin, OSX)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

How can one copy files from guest to host in Vagrant environment?

I know there are synced_folders but this doesn't work with darwin guest.
I need to copy build result from guest to host, ideally using vagrant provisioning scripts as all my other stuff happens there.

VM is VirtualBox.

Comment: You could install an http server in the guest and download it from outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your host use this command -

```
scp -P <vagrant guest ssh port number> vagrant@localhost:/path/to/source/file /path/to/destination/file
```

The "vagrant guest ssh port number" is the forwarded port from host to guest for ssh, and you can find this from the output of your vagrant up command.

Comment: I have ended up using this method. Would be nice if this could be done from provision scripts though.

Comment: You can use the [vagrant-host-shell plugin](https://github.com/phinze/vagrant-host-shell) to do this during provisioning.